# Syntax highlighting control for Mono?

Tags: c#, mono, scintilla

I can't seem to find any syntax highlighting widgets/controls for Mono. I know that GtkSourceView has a Mono version, but I can't actually find it anywhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2):

My favorite code editor control is [Scintilla](http://scintilla.org). It has native support for windows, gtk and cocoa.

An excellent .net wrapper is available at [ScintillaNET](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/) although I have no idea how well it supports gtk.

Comment: ScintillaNET does not work on Mono I'm afraid, and I don't know of a Scintilla wrapper that does.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look a the MonoDevelop editor?

https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/tree/master/main/src/core/Mono.Texteditor

Comment: Yes, though I can't seem to make it work. Dragging it as a control onto the GUI builder doesn't work, evidently.