# Add Scintilla to GTK# linux project

Tags: c#, linux, monodevelop, gtk#, scintilla

I’m just started a GTK# project in MonoDevelop IDE, and i want to use Scintilla code editor component.

After i get scintilla files from **[scintilla.org/ScintillaDownload.html](http://scintilla.org/ScintillaDownload.html)**, i try to add the control to my project library. In the open file dialog i can't select any files (program didn't find any suitable control).

I already makes the scintilla gtk folder, but still *nothing*.

**So my question is, how can i add scintilla control to my project?**

> OS: elementary OS 0.3.1 Freya (64-bit)
>
> IDE: MonoDevelop 5.9.6
>
> Component: Scintilla 3.6.1

And sorry for language mistakes! Thank you!

Comment: I do not think there is a Mono/C# binding for Scintilla. There is ScintillaNET but it is a wrapper to include it in WinForms (Windows only).

Comment: Are you sure? In this comment "Jake" says Scintilla has native support for gtk. Or this not means Mono/C# bindings exists? [Syntax highlighting control for Mono](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12505591/5352977)
And if not, you can offer an alternative to Scintilla? Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Mono provides GTK# (GTKSharp) which are binding for set of classes within the GTK2 libraries. So while you can use Scintilla within GTK using C/C++, you would need GTK#-style bindings to use it via Mono/C#. You of course could write those C# bindings ;-) http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/

Comment: Thank you very much! I gonna make it. Have a nice day!